# FacesException not being handled by standard error page

Tags: jsf, icefaces-1.8

there is one issue to which i don't find any specific answer. there is an ArrayOutOfBoundException thrown in a setter method called during render response phase since i have the value of that property set in my faces-config. Now, when this happens, it is not redirecting. What i could understand till now is it might be converting this exception to FacesException and so its not redirecting. Any views to handle this ? the call does not seem to be an ajax call too since it is coming when i click on a menu item.

Comment: Add a stacktrace and your managedBean code

Comment: Debug the request and the response and make sure it is really no Ajax request (partial-update).

Comment: @BholaVishwakarma: i am sry but i guess posting the stacktrace or managed bean code would not be possible. however i am not sure..why tht wld be necessary. the original prob can be again easily reproduced by simply configuring a standard error page and checking if it works on a FacesException. it is reproducible in a normal test webapp too..

Comment: @noone: i have already done that and came up with the conclusion that it is not an ajax call.. :)